# RStudio error: Unexpected symbol

Tags: r, rstudio, symbols

I have this code:

```
ChiSq_Variance_test=function(critical_Chi_score,critical_Chi_square){
  alfa=0.01;
  n=120;
  s_square=169;
  sigma_square=225;
  critical_Chi_square=qchisq(alfa,s-1);
  Chi_square_score=(n-1)*s_square/sigma_square;
  print(critical_Chi_square);
  print(Chi_square_score);
}ChiSq_Variance_test(6)
```

and it gives me this error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in:"enter code here }ChiSq_Variance_test"

If you know a solution please help me! Thank for your time!

Comment: the last line should be two lines. remove all those semicolons

Answer (score 0):

In R, in order to place two instructions on the same line, you should use semicolons like this: `n=120 ; b= 120`. However, at the end of a line, you do not need semicolons

Your code should be like this:

```
ChiSq_Variance_test=function(critical_Chi_score,critical_Chi_square){
  alfa=0.01
  n=120
  s_square=169
  sigma_square=225
  critical_Chi_square=qchisq(alfa,s-1)
  Chi_square_score=(n-1)*s_square/sigma_square
  print(critical_Chi_square)
  print(Chi_square_score)
}
ChiSq_Variance_test(6)
```

or like this:

```
ChiSq_Variance_test=function(critical_Chi_score,critical_Chi_square){
  alfa=0.01
  n=120
  s_square=169
  sigma_square=225
  critical_Chi_square=qchisq(alfa,s-1)
  Chi_square_score=(n-1)*s_square/sigma_square
  print(critical_Chi_square)
  print(Chi_square_score)
} ; ChiSq_Variance_test(6)
```